iOS 18 Control Center widget brake iOS 17 widgets
I have some weird issue with widgets after I created new control center widget.
This is the code example of my control center widget
@available(iOS 18.0, *)
struct OpenAppIntent: AppIntent {

    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Button Control Widget"

    static var isDiscoverable: Bool = false
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = true

    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & OpensIntent {
        return .result(opensIntent: OpenURLIntent())
    }
}

@available(iOS 18.0, *)
struct ActionButtonControlWidget: ControlWidget {

    let kind: String = "widget.ShortcutControlButtonWidget"

    var body: some ControlWidgetConfiguration {
        StaticControlConfiguration(kind: kind) {
            ControlWidgetButton(action: OpenAppIntent()) {
                Image("someimage")
                Text("someTitle")
            }
        }
    }
}

This is the code of WidgetBundle
struct WidgetBundle: SwiftUI.WidgetBundle {

    init() {
        //do some init
    }

    var body: some Widget {
        Widget1()
        Widget2()
        Widget3()
        Widget4()

        if #available(iOS 16.1, *) {
            LiveActivityWidget()
        }

        if #available(iOS 18.0, *) {
            ActionButtonControlWidget()
        }
    }
}

After this, on IOS 17 all widgets from home screen stops working and app does not see this widgets in widget center if you want to add new one. Maybe somebody faced this issue before. Thanks.
Generally, it does not look like a code issue because #available and @available are using correct.

This should fix the problem
var body: some Widget {
   if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 18.0, *) {
    return iOS18Widgets
   } else {
    return iOS17Widgets
   }
}

@WidgetBundleBuilder
var iOS17Widgets: some Widget {
   Widget1()
   Widget2()
   Widget3()
}

@available(iOSApplicationExtension 18.0, *)
@WidgetBundleBuilder
var iOS18Widgets: some Widget {
   Widget1()
   Widget2()
   Widget3()
   Widget4()
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
